# Please help with creating a proof of a statement in a propositional logic.

Tags: proof-writing, propositional-calculus

I have recently started to learn a propositional logic from a textbook. In one exercise I should make a proof of the following statement:

"If T is a set of premises and A is a premise, than T ⊨ A and T ⊨ ¬A, iff T is not satisfiable."

To me, it is obvious that this statement is true because I know that (T ⊨ A) ∧ (T ⊨ ¬A) is a contradiction and I also know that being a contradiction means that it is always false, which means that it is not satisfiable. Yet, I don't know if I can call this argument a proof of that statement.

How should I make a proof of that statement so that my teacher of mathematical logic would accept it as a proof?

Comment: If $T$ is not satisfiable, then there is no valuation that satisfies all formulas in $T$. Thus, every valuation that satisfies $T$ satisfies also $\varphi$, for a formula $\varphi$ whatever.

Comment: If $T \vDash A$ and $T \vDash \lnot A$, this means that every valuation that sat all formulas in $T$ satisfies both $A$ and $\lnot A$ : impossible.

Comment: Your proof seems to me to be similar to mine in one way. We both use statements which we don't prove further. For example, you used a statement: It is impossible to valuate formulas in T so that T satisfies both A and ¬A. This creates a question in my head: What particular level of a proof (in a way - what we should prove and what we take as not necessary to prove further) we accept as being enaugh to prove the statement? There is obviously more than just one way to prove such a statement.. (PS: I have never done proofs.)

Comment: The rules for truth valuation (see truth table) are defined in a way such that if for a valuation $v$ we have $v(A)= \text {TRUE}$, then $v(\lnot A)= \text {FALSE}$.